# What would be smart and fast way to find a pair of closest points in two sets?

Tags: java, algorithm, geometry, point

For example, I have two lists of points:

```
List<Point2D> a;
List<Point2D> b;
```

What would be the best way to find such `i` and `j`, so that `a.get(i).distance(b.get(j))` is minimal?

The obvious solution is brute-force - calculate distance from each point in `a` to each point in `b`, keep the pair with shortest distance. But this algorithm is `O(n^2)`, which is not good. Is there some better approach?

Comment: With algorithms like this one, you should always think about what happens if you *sort* your input.

Comment: Are the lists sorted in any way?

Comment: @alestanis By what would you sort a set of x/y coordinates to make that happen?

Comment: @alestanis - For example, I sort them by .getX. How can I then get closest pair?

Comment: Have a look at scanline algorithms.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson right! I missed the `Point2D`! Sorry about that

Comment: If one of the lists is stable, then there's a largish literature about indexing low-dimensional spaces. You can then use the index to get better average  If both of the lists are different each time, then from memory the best you can do it brute force. (It's an old memory, though, as evidenced by my wrong answer below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For every point of list `a` you can find the nearest point from list `b` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13000634/1009831). Time complexity is O((M+N) log M). N = |A|, M = |B|.

Then you just search the point in `a`, having the nearest neighbor. Time complexity is O(N).

Answer (score 3):

You can put one of the lists in a [quad tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) or some other spatial index to make each lookup fast.

As an alternative you could put all your data in a database with spatial index capabilites.